# Cannot use transfer or send on solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

I use Ganache, truffle.

I get the following error:

```
Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction
```

I have located the problematic piece of code:

```
        bool sent = _sellerAddress.send(_price);
```

Now, I get the price via the user interaction, and when the price is 0, then the error is not thrown,
unfortunately in the classic case when the _price is no zero, the exception is thrown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, it's not enough information to detect the exact problem, but just assuming that it's an ether transfer from your contract : are you sure that your contract has enough funds to send ( >0). If you're using latest version of solidity try payable(msg.sender).transfer(_price). Do not use send. You can find difference in solidity docs

Comment: @VladyslavMunin Hi, the issue is not about Send/Transfer/Call methods. I try to pass the ether between two users and not between a user and a contract. I have concluded that I need to move the functionality from the contract into the UI and using there in Web3 API. Or to change all the architectures of my DApp by adding a contract which owned by the other user who I want to pass to him the ether. What solution do you think is preferred? If I'm in the right direction of course.